# How to get data or identify tag <b> i.e Successfully Completed using Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

```
<TABLE height="100%" cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width="100%" border=0>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD height="100%" vAlign=top width="86%" align=center>
<TABLE cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width="80%" border=0>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD vAlign=top align=center>
<TABLE class=table_border_dark cellSpacing=1 cellPadding=0 width="80%" border=0>
<TBODY>
<TR align=center>
<TD bgColor=#ffffff colSpan=2>
<TABLE class=table_border_dark cellSpacing=1 cellPadding=1 width="60%" border=0>
<TBODY><LEGEND><B>Successfully Completed</B></LEGEND></TBODY></TABLE></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE>
```

I tried with:

```
boolean table = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='eodProgress']/..//b[contains(text(),'EOD Process Successfully Completed')]")).isDisplayed();
System.out.println(table);
```

But I received an error, that it is unable to find the element.

Comment: While manipulating you have massacred the HTML and currently it's not a valid HTML. Update the question with the HTML as it is.

Comment: Updated HTML code as it is , thanks .

Comment: You took out the `<TBODY>` and closing `<TABLE>` tags and added the text **EOD Process** within the  innerHTML. But unfortunately the HTML is still invalid. You have messed up the position of `<TD>` and `<LEGEND>` tags.

Comment: Why are you taking the pain to manipulate the HTML? Just copy and paste it. That's it. Won't cause any harm.

Comment: there was some error with my copy paste, it not copying the text as it is

Comment: Your sample html does not appear to contain the text you are searching for `EOD Process Successfully Completed`

Answer (score 1):

To extract the text within `<b>` tag i.e **Successfully Completed** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *visibilityOfElementLocated* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  String myText = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("TABLE.table_border_dark LEGEND>B"))).getAttribute("innerHTML");
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  String myText = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//TABLE[@class='table_border_dark']//LEGEND/B"))).getAttribute("innerHTML");
  ```

Comment: Apologies I should have provided the full HTML code, because there are multiple class with the same value (tableborderdark). I will update the HTML code again.

Comment: @manisha If your requirement have changed feel free to raise a new question. Stack Overflow contributors will be happy to help you out.